# Use typedef/using from templated base class in derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11, typedef

In accessing a `using` from a base class with a templated base class, I've run into an issue with verbosity if nothing else.  In the below code, the derived class attempts to use the `my_type` from its base class.

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
    public:
        using mytype = T;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T>{
    public:
        // using the base's mytype here
        static typename Base<T>::mytype func() { return 0;}
};
```

However, in practice I'm finding this to be an awful lot of characters for what seems like it should be simpler.  if the Base class was not templated then it wouldn't require the `<T>` or the typename (obviously).

In my real issue, I have a great deal of classes deriving from the base and I want to simplify this if possible.  What I have at the moment is like the next example, where I'm just adding an additional `using` to get the type from the base class, but it feels like an extra layer that I shouldn't need to have.

```
template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T>{
    public:
        using base_type = typename Base<T>::mytype;
        static base_type func() { return 0;}
};
```

this may seem like a silly issue, but the number of times the base class's `mytype` is used in the derived classes makes it pretty hideous in the former case.  Is there a *right* way to get the types out of the templated base that maintains readability?

Comment: There is nothing that you can really do there. The language is as it is and this is a requirement on how lookup is performed.

Comment: I agree with @DavidRodríguez-dribeas. Your solution with `using` or a `typedef` is what I would use, too.

Comment: Of course, you can slightly shorten it by, say, `using base = Base<T>; static typename base::mytype func();` or, `using self = Derived; static typename self::mytype func();`.

Comment: You are setting `mytype` to be `T` in the base, and are passing in `T` as a template parameter on your derived class.  Why not just use `T` as your return type for your function?

Comment: @ZacHowland it's a simplified example.  There's a lot of `decltype`ing involved in the real version

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a well known quirk of the language for which there is no real solution. Lookup in templates is done in two separate steps, during the first phase of lookup *before* instantiation non-dependent names are resolved to their meanings, while in the second phase dependent names are resolved *after* instantiation.

The division of the two phases was included in the language to provide some sanity for the template developer that does not know where the template will be instantiated. The first phase of lookup is done at the point where the template is defined, and it can be reasoned about by the developer at exactly that point. At one point or another, the template will do operations that depend on the arguments, and those cannot be resolved where the template is defined, since the template arguments are not yet fixed. Those names are considered dependent, and lookup is postponed to the second phase, after substitution of the template arguments, so that ADL can kick in.

How does this relate to your particular problem? When you inherit from a non-template base, the developer has fixed what the base is, and that can be looked up at the point of the template definition as you expect. But when the base depends on a template argument, the definition of the base *class* is not known at the place of the derived template definition. In particular, without substituting the type in, the compiler cannot possibly know whether there is a specialization for this particular type. This implies that during the first phase the compiler cannot assume anything at all about the base and thus lookup cannot search into it.

The direct way of using a typedef in a base is for the developer of the derived template to explicitly tell the compiler that it wants a type and that the type *will* be defined in the instantiation of the base template. The key point here is that the compiler knows nothing about the base, but the developer can *require* that uses of this template comply with a contract in which the instantiation of the base *must* have that nested type. The developer is free to add constraints on the types of her template, the compiler is not.

The syntax for that is the one in your first block: `typename Base<T>::type` to refer to the type, which tells the compiler that the contract of use requires that whatever `T` is used to instantiate `Derived`, the user is required to ensure that `Base<T>` will contain a nested member `type` that is a type (`typename`). As a short hand, you can opt for the second approach: create a local typedef that will be found inside `Derived` and resolved to that. In that case, regular lookup during the first phase will find the nested typedef, determine that it refers to a dependent name and postpone the complete lookup for the second phase.

While this is not an answer to the question of whether there is a *better* way (readability wise), I hope it provides some understanding as of why things are like they are. The decision while designing the language was not arbitrary [it might or not be ideal, some people believe the first phase is unneeded and unwanted, but it was not arbitrary]

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, but you can simply use `using` on the type directly without having to give it a new name:

```
template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T>{
public:
    using typename Base<T>::mytype;
    static mytype func() { return 0;}
};
```

You can even decide if the `using`-declaration for `mytype` should go into the `public`, `protected` or `private` section.

Comment: This is fine as long as there aren't too many `mytype`s in the base classes, or as long as you're comfortable with using-declarations. I think the OP looked for a direct way, avoiding any alias- or using-declaration in the derived class.